# Camera transition with rotation

Tags: three.js

I got a question about camera object. I'm trying to make a transition between cameras and I got it partially working. Camera is moving well but it does not rotate correct. I suppose my code does not calculate lookAtVector right but I cannot find information how to do it correct.
Here is the code I'm using:

```js
var new_position = new_camera.position.clone();
var new_rotation = new_camera.rotation.clone();
var new_quaternion = new_camera.quaternion.clone();

camera.rotation.clone(new_rotation);
camera.quaternion.clone(new_quaternion);

newlookAtVector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1);
newlookAtVector.applyEuler(new_rotation, new_camera.eulerOrder);


new TWEEN.Tween( camera.position ).to( {
        x: new_position.x,
        y: new_position.y,
        z: new_position.z}, 600 ).onUpdate(function () {

 camera.lookAt(newlookAtVector);

}).onComplete(function () {

 camera.lookAt(newlookAtVector);

}).easing( TWEEN.Easing.Sinusoidal.Out).start();
```

Thank you!